# ARM9 Exception causing system crash and generating core dump

Tags: linux, exception, arm, toolchain

I am using ARM toolchain to cross compile my driver and application code. Gcc-4.2.1, uClibc-0.29.x,binutils-2.19 etc.

My application is crashing by generating a core dump (Segmentation fault). When I analyzed the core dump, I see that crash happens in `_Unwind_VRS_Pop()` call. It's crashing while writing a return address to a local pointer.

Actually  `_Unwind_VRS_Pop()` will be called when there is an exception. Based on ARM documents available online, I see the source of exception is Prefetched Abort.

As per my understanding, when an exception happens, the CPU should store the current register status and return address and quit (when there is no MMU). But in my case, the application is crashing. When analysed the core it shows backtrace with `_Unwind_VRS_Pop()` as frame 0 (crash in this function). Is this fault with application or toolchain?

Important points to mention:

1. In my application, I am using a fixed memory pool for all operations. If I increase this memory pool (heap area), I dont see this issue.
2. even tried upgrading my toolchain gcc version to 4.2.4. I still see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`_Unwind_VRS_Pop` is part of the C++ exception handling implementation.  C++ exceptions are quite different from the hardware exceptions like Prefetch and Data Abort.

In this case you seem to be getting one of each:  first a C++ exception is being thrown (maybe `bad_alloc`?) and then instead of terminating nicely the exception handling code is crashing with a hardware exception, which the OS turns into a seg fault signal and dumps core.  Usually the core dump will show the process at the point when the hardware exception happened before the processor entered the exception mode - possibly with the PC pointing to or just past the offending instruction.

This might be a toolchain bug, or your application might be accidentally overwriting data that the exception handling implementation uses.

You might try a small program that throws and catches a C++ exception to see if it works in a small example.  If that works try throwing an exception that you don't catch and see if the behaviour is still reasonable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.I will try try and catch application as you suggeted.  I also would like to add some information. This failure is called during pthread_exit(). As I can see following call sequence happens in normal thread exit sequence, pthread_exit() -> do_cancel() -> __pthread_unwind -> __gnu_Unwind_ForcedUnwind()->unwind_phase2_forced()->unwind_stop(). In failure case, the flow deviates from unwind_phase2_forced() and reaches Unwind_VRS_Pop. What is the cause of c++ exceptionan way to track down ? We have C ABI and C++ ABI, how to confirm that my code is using which ABI ?